# Formatting float with sprintf fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, printf

I am trying to create a formatted string (actually a char array) using sprintf in C++.
The input variables are a floating point value `float fps`, an unsinged integer `unsinged int timeStepCount` and the buffer to write to `char out[256]`.
I am calling sprintf as follows:

```
sprintf(out, "%4.1f FPS %10d time steps", fps, timeStepCount);
```

The `timeStepCount` gets formatted correctly (there are spaces added when the number is shorter than ten digits) but `fps` is not. It only gets as many digits as it actually needs. Did I forget something?
I am using Visual Studio 2008, if that helps :)

Comment: You don't say exactly what format you're expecting or what you're getting, but remember the the first number is the total width, not the number of digits before the decimal point. So if you're expecting `12.3` and `123.4` to be correctly aligned, then you'll need a wider width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format `%4.1f` says "print `fps` using a width of at least four characters, with one digit after the decimal point".

You always have at least one digit before the decimal, the decimal, and one digit after the decimal, that's at least three of the requested four `char`s. If the value of `fps` is between 0 (inclusive) an 10 (exclusive), you get one space of padding, otherwise none.

If you want four characters including the padding *before* the decimal point, you need `%6.1f`, since two places are used for the point and the digit after.